# problems with appending text to text file?

Tags: c#, append, streamwriter

i am trying to write a code where the user enters delivery details into text box and the text gets added to a txt file (notepad txt file).
This is my attempt, i get an extra line with " , ," why does it not add the text from textbox to the text file?

```
private void FrmDelivery_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theDelivery != null)
    {
        txtCustomerName.Text = theDelivery.customerName;
        txtCustomerAddress.Text = theDelivery.customerAddress;
        txtArrivalTime.Text = theDelivery.arrivalTime;      
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("visits.txt", true)) //true shows that text would be appended to file
        {
            writer.WriteLine(theDelivery.customerName + ", " + theDelivery.customerAddress + ", " + theDelivery.arrivalTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: theDelivery is the object which is created from the class Delivery

Comment: Code for writing to file looks fine, you even get `" , ,"`. So use the debugger and find out why `theDelivery.customerName` etc is empty.

Comment: -1. Please align your title and sample code: your title asks about how to append to file, but your code and text of the question say that append works perfectly fine just with no values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're writing to the file on `Form_Load`. I assume that you only want to write to it when the user has changed something.

So you could handle a save-button's click-event to write to it:

```
private void FrmDelivery_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theDelivery != null)
    {
        txtCustomerName.Text = theDelivery.customerName;
        txtCustomerAddress.Text = theDelivery.customerAddress;
        txtArrivalTime.Text = theDelivery.arrivalTime;      
    }
} 

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}{3}"
                , txtCustomerName.Text 
                , txtArrivalTime.Text  
                , theDelivery.arrivalTime
                , Environment.NewLine);
    File.AppendAllText("visits.txt", line);   
}
```

[`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) is just another (comfortable) way to write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

..because you're not writing the contents of the textboxes to the file.. you're writing variables (that don't appear to be initialized anywhere):

Fixed:

```
writer.WriteLine(txtCustomerName.Text + ", " + txtCustomerAddress.Text + ", " + txtArrivalTime.Text); // Fixed.
```

Also, you're doing this on Form load.. is there data in the textboxes at this point (or is `theDelivery` initialized)?

Comment: i have two forms, in the main form there is a list box which displays deliveries and when you click on one of the deliveries, its details is displayed in another form

Comment: Then there are bigger problems in your code. Put a breakpoint on that line.. is there any data in either the textboxes or the variables?

Comment: there are data entered into the textboxes

Comment: ..is the data there when the form loads though? Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: i have a txt file which contains data and gets loaded in at the start

Answer (score 0):

Your customerName, customerAddress and arrivalTime string properties of the Delivery object insatance are all initialized to an empty string. You should set some string before you write to the file.